# dynamic ajax success property ..very weird

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

My intentions are as follows: 
I have a list of songs with a delete link next to each song.
Sometimes if the song does not exist or was deleted the list renders an add button instead.
when I user clicks the Add link a song is added and a "song was added successfully" message appears, similar thing happens when a user succesfully deletes a song. 
The Problem is that when the user first deletes a song and right after that he wants to add a song the same message appears that appeared when he deleted a song and vice versa, when a user first adds the song "song was added sucessfully" msg poppes out and then when he clicks delete song the "song was added sucessfully" msg appers instead of the "song was deleted succesfully". I believe it has something to do with the proper binding and unbinding event handlers but not sure how to fix this weird situation.

this is my jquery click add song function:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".btnAddCurrentFav", function () {
        var txtLink = $('#youTubeLinkTxt').val();
        var txtName = $('#youTubeNameTxt').val();
        var subLink = txtLink.substr(31); //.replace(/.*\?v=/, '');
        var id = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
        $('#hiddenRank').val(id);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/AddCurrentFav",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#AddTopTenFavForm").serialize(),
            success: ShowMsg("Song Added Successfully"),
            error: ShowMsg("Song could not be added, please try again")
        });

        $(this).replaceWith('<a name="' + subLink + '" class="topTenFavLinks"  href="#" >' + txtName + '</a>');

        $('#youTubeLinkTxt').val('');
        $('#youTubeNameTxt').val('');
    });
```

this is my ShowMsg function:

```
  function ShowMsg(parameter) {
    $("#msg").find("span").replaceWith(parameter);
    $("#msg").css("display", "inline");
    $("#msg").fadeOut(3000);
 }
```

This is my jquery click delete song function:

```
  $(".btnDeleteCurrentFavSong").click(function () {
    var button = $(this);
    var songId = $(this).attr('name');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Home/DeleteCurrentFav/",
        data: { id: songId },
        success: ShowSuccessMsgAndReplaceCurrentSong("Song deleted successfully",button),
        error: ShowMsg("Song could not be deleted, please try again"),
    });
});
```

And here is the showsuccess function for the delete action:

```
 function ShowSuccessMsgAndReplaceCurrentSong(parameter,button) {
    $(button).siblings().replaceWith('<a class="btnAddCurrentFav icons">+</a>');
    $(button).remove();
    $("#msg").find("span").replaceWith(parameter);
    $("#msg").css("display", "inline");

    $("#msg").fadeOut(3000);
}
```

Comment: You should not do this: `$("#msg").find("span").replaceWith(parameter);`. [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) replace the selected element by the one provided, so your <span> is replaced by the text. Do this: `$("#msg").find("span").text(parameter);`

Comment: The OP also needlessly rewraps button in $() within ShowSuccess..., it is already a jquery object. Also, watch for extra commas within object literals, they break some browsers. There is one after the error handler in the second example.

Comment: Would be better to not add/remove your action links all the time to the DOM. Create the Add and Remove links once for all and simply hide one or the other.

Comment: ok the problem was with the replaceWith jquery method, i changed it to .text and everything works now :D thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might come from this line:

```
$("#msg").find("span").replaceWith(parameter);
```

[.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) replaces an element by the other element provided as paremeter, it does not change the text inside the span, it replaces the span with the text !

So the next time, $("#msg").find("span") does not work, and only the #msg element is faded, so you see the previous message.

Instead do this:

```
$("#msg").find("span").text(parameter);
```

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/RNbPA/) for a live example of the problem.
This [other one](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/GfKLW/) sees the correction.

Comment: By the way, even if that was not solving the problem, what BNL says is true as well, you should wrap your event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

You are executing your success function immediately rather then setting it up to be an event handler.

```
success: ShowMsg("Song Added Successfully"), // This executes the ShowMsg function, it does not set it as an event handler.
```

Wrap it in an anonymous function.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/Home/DeleteCurrentFav/",
    data: { id: songId },
    success: function () { ShowSuccessMsgAndReplaceCurrentSong("Song deleted successfully",button); },
    error: function () { ShowMsg("Song could not be deleted, please try again"); } //, remove this comma!
});
```

There is also an extra comma after the error property in the posted code.